# SQL Server 2012 Express Database Backup Script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup, sql-server-express

I want to do a full weekly backup of my SQL Server 2012 Express database.

I have created a SQL script and batch file to automatically do a full backup of my database each week and overwrite the existing backup file each time this script is executed.

I am wondering if my syntax is correct and is doing what I intend it to do.

```
BACKUP DATABASE test TO  
DISK = N'\\path\to\backup\folder\TestBackup.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT
    , INIT  
    , NAME = N'test Backup'
    , SKIP
    , NOREWIND
    , NOUNLOAD
    , STATS = 10;
```

Is there anything incorrect in the above backup statement?

Comment: `NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD` are superfluous in your case.  since they are tape drive-specific options that will have no effect when performing the backup to disk.  `NOFORMAT` simply indicates not to overwrite the header in the backup file - this is the default behavior, and is unnecessary when combined with the `INIT` option which overwrites all backups in the backup file.  You may want to look at the SQL Server Books Online topic about the `BACKUP` command at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct.

It will backup your database to `\\path\to\backup\folder\TestBackup.bak`.

`INIT` will overwrite the file everytime it backups up.

Are you sure you just want one FULL backup ? What about transaction log backups? What if that backup gets corrupted (since you have only one backup and that is being overwritten everytime you take a new full backup) ?

Better append datetime at the end of backup.

I would suggest you to use the script at [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express ?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698?wa=wsignin1.0)